# IE7 image won't constrain itself if parent has width set

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have a gradient image that I'm using as the background for a variable-height container.  The basic structure is simply (more complex than this, but just as a reference):

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="..." style="width: 100%;height:100%;">
    <div class="content">
        content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

Works great, in every browser, until I add an explicit width to `.parent`, and then guess which browser chokes?  IE7!  I love IE7 so much!

What happens is that the image ratio now resets, making it `960x960` since my `.parent` is 960px wide.  Basically it seems to be ignoring the `height:100%`

I set up a fiddle to show the exact issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/SsYSv/2/

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i have reveised my answer,

basically wrap a div around the containing div `.banner` and set the width to that div.

http://jsfiddle.net/SsYSv/6/

```
<!--[if IE 7]><div class="ieBanner"><![endif]-->
     ...
<!--[if IE 7]></div><![endif]-->

.ieBanner
{
    width:400px;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  No real need for the conditional though, as the same thing would work in other browsers and just make debugging that much more annoying :)